# Weird Windows 7 behaviors when downloading or installing

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, download

I am seeing some odd issues on a new Windows 7 HP laptop. The OS is 64 bit OS. Attempting to download anything in the 32 bit IE included will show a progress bar and after complete nothing happens, this happens if I choose run or save. Choosing save and a location the file never appears in a given location.

When attempting to install and run gotoassist the message "Can't find program files folder" appears.

Trying to install Adobe Acrobat 9 nets the error "Unable to create the temporary folder. Error 1008-An attempt was made to
reference a token that does not exist. "

When right clicking Computer and going to properties nothing happens.

Normally I would assume virus or malware but its a brand new pc, any suggestions?

EDIT: As a side note, the error from Gotoassist occured in IE 64 bit, the 64 bit browser will allow me to download unlike 32 bit

Comment: Have you restarted your computer? Sometimes IE problems go away if you do. Have you done a `sfc /scannow` to check system files to make sure they're okay? Have you done a `chkdsk` to check the file system?

Answer (score -1):

If you are running a 32 bit computer, the only programs it should run are 32 bit programs, and likewise with 64 bit, so that may be the reason.

Also, a 64 bit computer cannot save/run 32 bit programs and applications.

If that's not the reason, it's okay, there's always Firefox and Chrome

Comment: The last line is useful, but the first part is just wrong